# PyCharm SetUp existing env

Tags: pycharm

I've updated existing win app to newer version 2019.3.1.

Now I'm not able to use project specific virtual environments.
When I'm open with Ctrl + Alt + S the Settings menue and take a look at Project Interpreter it use nothing. And I'm not able define the settings to use project specific env.

When I'm add a Python interpreter and choose "New envrionment" pycharm tell me that the path is not empty. That is right. When I choose "Existing environment", e.g. C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\python\robotics1\venv, I'm not able to click on the "OK" button.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! The .idea was corrupt!
Thanks